# Wrapping up the text inside an `<li>` element

Tags: html, css

I've created a form, where I have a side nav-bar. In that, all the `<li>` elements are placed such a way that two `<li>`s fall in one line. Now, the problem is, whenever the text of a `<li>` element increases, it affects the other `<li>` elements. This is how I've tried:

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
    
    /* Toggle Styles */
    
#wrapper {
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
    
#wrapper.toggled {
  padding-left: 250px;
}
    
#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 250px;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
    
#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
}
    
#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
}
    
#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -250px;
}
    
  /* Sidebar Styles */
    
.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-indent: -2em;
}
    
.sidebar-nav li {
  text-indent: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
    
.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999999;
}
    
.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}
    
.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
    
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 60px;
}
    
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
  color: #999999;
}
    
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}
    
.sidebar-nav_wrapper    {
  float:left;
  margin-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar-nav_wrapper">
    <h4 class="sidebar-brand">Select Field Type</h4>
    <ul class="sidebar-nav" style="margin-top: 40px;">
     
      <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#SingleLine_Modal">Single Line</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#PickList_Modal">Pick List</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MultiSelect_Modal">Multi Select</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MultiLine_Modal">Multi Line</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Email_Modal">Email</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Phone_Modal">Phone Number</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Mobile_Modal">Mobile Number</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar-nav_wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav" style="margin-top: 40px; margin-left: -20px;">
      <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Date_Modal">Date</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Time_Modal">Time</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DateTime_Modal">Date-Time</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CheckBox_Modal">Checkbox</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Radio_Modal">Radio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Decimal_Modal">Decimal</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Number_Modal">Number</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AutoNumber_Modal">Auto Number</a></li>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want is, whenever the text size of a `<li>` increases, only few letters should be shown outside, succeeded by `..`. I've provided my css and HTML. I don't know what to correct and where to correct. So, can someone help me to achieve what I want?

Comment: where is your html? Better create a code snippet reproducing your problem

Comment: I just tested your code and after a bit of fiddling I got it to show up - Why are you creating two separate UL LI structures for a slide in multi-leveled menu? (I assume that's your goal?).

ALSO, please provide a jsFiddle so we can see what you're looking at.

Comment: Please reduce the question down to a few dozen lines of code, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `white-space: nowrap;` to prevent text from wrapping to a second line, and `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to display `...` instead of an overflowing text part

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code ,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">
<title>Location Retriever</title>
<style>
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
 }

/* Toggle Styles */

#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -250px;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-indent: -2em;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}

.sidebar-nav_wrapper    {
    float:left;
    margin-left:5px;
} 
li{

}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar-nav_wrapper">
             <h4 class="sidebar-brand">Select Field Type</h4>
          <ul class="sidebar-nav" style="margin-top: 40px;">

             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#SingleLine_Modal">Single Line</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#PickList_Modal">Pick Listxcvxvccvxcv</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MultiSelect_Modal">Multi Select</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MultiLine_Modal">Multi Linesdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Email_Modal">Emailsdfsdf</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Phone_Modal">Phone Numberdfsdf</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Mobile_Modal">Mobile Numbersdfsdf</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-nav_wrapper">
          <ul class="sidebar-nav" style="margin-top: 40px; margin-left: -20px;">
             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Date_Modal">Datexcvxcvxcvxcv</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Time_Modal">Time</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DateTime_Modal">Date-Time</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CheckBox_Modal">Checkbox</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Radio_Modal">Radio</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Decimal_Modal">Decimal</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Number_Modal">Number</a></li>
             <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AutoNumber_Modal">Auto Number</a></li>
    </ul>
        </div>
</div>
<script>
var listItems=$("li a");
for(var i=0;i<listItems.length;i++){
if (listItems[i].innerText.length>12){
listItems[i].style.whiteSpace="nowrap"; 
var firstPart=listItems[i].innerText.substring(0,12);
var secPart=listItems[i].innerText.substring(12,listItems[i].innerText.length);
listItems[i].innerText=listItems[i].innerText.slice(0,12);
listItems[i].innerHTML+="<span onclick='clickSpan(this)' title="+secPart+">...</span>";

var text=listItems[i].innerHTML;
console.log("getting text "+text);
}
}

function clickSpan(span){
 span.innerText=span.title;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You will have to increase the width of the navigation bar.SO this is what i have done.

- I have introduced a span element depending on the length of the text in the list element.
- if the length is greater than 12 then the span tag is created after the anchor tag and after the first part of the string.
- The text within the anchor tag will be "...".In case we want to view the extra text you have to click the "..." part and the extra part of the text will be viewed alongside the previous text.
- You can tweak the code for the extra text to appear "onhover" or any other event.
- You can also change the word limit of the text after which the span must appear